# How deep should I bury a 4x4 steel post?

Tags: steel, post

I live in West Texas. I need to put up a 4x4 steel post to mount a camera. How deep do I need to bury it? There will be 15 feet above ground.

Comment: The standard advice for fence posts is 1/3rd below ground, so if it's 15' above, you'd have 7.5' below. But at 15', I would consider some support wires or bracing to make the post more stable without having to dig so deep. Is that an option?

Comment: @BMitch:  33% below ground seems intuitively excessive.  When I place a 4x4 fence post, if it is to be 6 feet high, then 2 feet go below ground:  1/4.

Comment: @wallyk but this just seems to be a single post, whereas a fence has other supporting boards and such. I'd do what bMitch said. Plus there can be very strong winds in west texas, so better to overdo it in this case, then worry.

Comment: Third option, considering it's steel, is to weld some support to the bottom so it's not "just" a pole. Or, indeed, to put a full-on concrete foundation with 3-4 mounting bolts sticking up and a flange with 3-4 holes on the post, and mount it that way. I suspect, given 20 foot sticks as a common steel stock size, that 5 feet in the ground will be the most cost-efficient way, but I'd be a lot more comfortable with that if there were some triangulated braces in the ground, perhaps made from weldable rebar and cast in concrete. Need not come above ground if it's more convenient as a monopole.

Comment: Are you sure a 4x4 steel post is not overkill?  Wouldn't 2" pipe be a better fit for mounting a camera?  Where is this camera getting mounted?  Parking lot?  Field?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to bury about 1/4 of the pole under ground (So dig a 6 foot hole). At the bottom of the hole, pour 1 foot of gravel, and then put in the pole. Now pour a bunch of cement (4+ bags), and make sure your pole is placed strait in the hole. Now shovel your dirt on top and you're good to go!